# How to enforce static member initialization in template types? or How to get the count of all classes, that were derived from template type?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, automation

Consider the following code:

```
uint sNextId = 0;
uint GetNextId() { return sNextId++; }
uint GetIdCount() { return sNextId; }

class TBase<T>
{
    static const uint sId = GetNextId();
    ...
}

class DerivedA : TBase<DerivedA>
{ ... }

class DerivedB : TBase<DerivedB>
{ ... }

... More classes ...
```

At some point at the start of my program

```
void main()
{
     ... Initialization code ...
     ... here I can guarantee that no derived classes were created ...
     ... but no guarantee that all those derived classes were 'touched' here ...

     AllocateMemory();

     ... Using allocated memory, creating derived classes ...
}
```

I want to know how many derived classes have specialized classes `TBase<T>` by calling `GetIdCount()` to allocate all required space only once in `AllocateMemory()`. I do not have any dynamic libraries but I can link static libs to executable (which can use this `TBase<T>` for creating more derived types).

My question to *C++ Jedi* is:

How to automate the process of initialization `sId` static members so that `sNextId`was correct and was not incremented after the memory was allocated? Note, that I don't want to have something explicit (i.e. I don't want to write additional code except to add a new class `C`, that inherit `TBase<C>`). Ideally, the mechanism should work by just inheriting from `TBase<T>`, or additionally inheriting from a non-template class, it should not contain any timers or smth, memory barriers or something even more sophisticated. No multithreading is considered. Classes can inherit additionally a non-template type, that will do work for us too, but it should not be 'heavy', as well as 'TBase'.

Thanks!

Comment: static member variables can't be initialized during declaration from within the class .

Comment: Please tell us why you need to determine your memory requirements.  I don't know how you can determine your memory requirements using this technique without making unrealistic assumptions, like: each derived class is instantiated once and only once, each derived class needs no additional memory, etc.

Comment: @seccpur, exactly, and I'm asking to suggest a way of how to get `sId` static members initialized before some particular place in the code, thanks.

Comment: You can define a  Singleton inherited class within the class.

Comment: @Loring, I have a scene, which has nodes, each node has components. When I create a node, I want to know how many different component types exists, so that I could allocate memory in the constructor for each type. Each component type inherits some `TComponentBase` with `sId`. I want to have a template accesssor `T * Get<T>() { static_assert(is_base<T, TComponentBase>); return pComponents[T::sId]; }`

Comment: @seccpur, could you, please, provide an example of usage, because I do not quite understand the idea of having a singleton within the class (did you mean singleton inside TBase?).

Comment: @Loring, it is important for me to have that kind of access, I cannot search for component with particular sId each time I want to access it, runtime type info does not suit me too + I don`t case much about unused memory.

Comment: @VladSerhiienko please update your question with the information from your comments.  Also, why can't each type/instance allocate its own memory?  Why do you need that accessor?  You are telling us your low level requirements but it would be helpful to know the higher level goal so we might suggest a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably something based on the idea that is behind the [nifty counter](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Nifty_Counter) is what you are looking for.
From the linked documentation, the intent is:

> Ensure a non-local static object is initialized before its first use and destroyed only after last use of the object.

You can do it so that *is initialized* means *a counter somewhere is incremented*, thus access to that counter.
Of course, you can still use CRTP to do that.

Answer (score -1):

Working from mobile phone, trying a short snippet.

```
     class book
     {
           class empty_book: public book
           {  
                 private:
                      int pages = 0;

                 public:
                  static const empty_book& get()
                  {
                    static const empty_book p=  empty_book();
                    return p;
                   }
              };
          void foo()
          {
              int pages = empty_book::get().val();
              this = empty_book::get();
           }
      };
```